# How to know if user input a string or a number using interactive

Tags: string, interactive

I want to check if a user input a word or a number. And I write the function look like this:

```
(defun check-input (arg)
  "description"
  (interactive "senter arg: ")
  (setq isnum (string-match "\\'[0-9]+\\'" arg))
  (if isnum
      (message "INPUT is number ")
  (message "INPUT is string ")))
```

But every time I enter whether the a number of a word, it just show "Input is string". Can you help me where did I go wrong. Thanks you very much

Comment: 1. What others have said, regarding your use of `string-match`. 2. Use `string-match-p`. 3. Bind `isnum` with `let`, instead of using a global variable - or just put the test sexp directly in your `if` (no variable `isnum`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> (setq isnum (string-match "\\'[0-9]+\\'" arg))
> ```

That should be `` (setq isnum (string-match "\\`[0-9]+\\'" arg)) ``

`` \\` `` means beginning of string, `\\'` means end of string.

See [`(elisp) Regexp Backslash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish here, you can use `(string-to-number arg)`. This will return 0 if the argument is a string that cannot be parsed as a number; otherwise, it just returns the value converted to a number.

Comment: this worked too, thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the quotes or backslashes in your regexp.  Change it to just `(string-match "[0-9]+" arg)` and I believe it ought to do what you want.

Comment: That would say "number" for inputs like `abc123`.